# code coverage of xDebug and PHPUnit says 100%, in fact it is not

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage, xdebug

I have the following function:

```
function foo($p)
{
    if ($p == null)
        throw new Exception('bla');
    if ($p == null)
    {
        throw new Exception('bla');
    }
    [...]
}
```

My Test for this function is not covering the lines throwing the exception. But PHPUnit tells me the first 'throw'-statement is coverd, the second not. Maybe the first is interpreted, but it is not executed.

So I don't want to get the message '100%' if I have not reached 100%.

Is this a bug in xDebug or do I have the possibility to configure xDebug/PHPUnit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

xDebug's code coverage metrics are statement-based rather than line-based. What this means is that a control structure without a block enclosed in braces is treated as a single statement. To let xDebug see the `throw` line as separate from the `if()` test, surround it with braces as you did in the second statement.

```
if ($p == null)                    // statement 1
    throw new Exception('bla');    // rest of statement 1
```

vs.

```
if ($p == null) {                  // statement 1
    throw new Exception('bla');    // statement 2
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Do you know if xDebug is supporting other coverage methods like branch or condition?

Comment: @user1027167 xDebug works on statements but provides line base coverage information only

Comment: User1026176, I have plans to add branch/condition coverage, but didn't have the time so far.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because xDebug can't provide better data, as it is only aware of statements and not of 'lines' and is documented in the PHPUnit documentation under:

[**`Code coverage analysis - Edge Cases`**](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/code-coverage-analysis.html#code-coverage-analysis.edge-cases):

```
<?php
// Due to how code coverage works internally these two lines are special.
// This line will show up as non executable
if(false)
    // This line will show up as covered because it is actually the 
    // coverage of the if statement in the line above that gets shown here!
    will_also_show_up_as_coveraged();

// To avoid this it is necessary that braces are used
if(false) {
    this_call_will_never_show_up_as_covered();
}
```

The same goes for the `$x ? $y : $z;` construct. The only way to avoid this behavior is to add curly braces.

Answer (score -1):

Its pretty bad when you have to modify your source to overcome flaws of the tools you are using.

Our [PHP Test Coverage Tool](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/TestCoverage/PHPTestCoverage.html) doesn't have this problem.

In addition, if you place several statements in the same line, ours will track them individually. I believe XDebug will mark the "line" as covered if any part of the first statement in the line is covered.  I believe it will do this even for the following:

```
if (... )  { .... }
```

So you will get "false" coverage reported for the block controlled by the conditional, even if the conditional is always false.