# What does Xdebug in PHP return?

Tags: php, code-coverage, xdebug

This code with PHP/Xdebug (using Xdebug 2.2.1 and PHP 5.4 on Windows 7 x64, also I have added a line counter for readability):

```
1: xdebug_start_code_coverage();
2:
3: for ($ii = 0; $ii < 3; ++$ii)
4:    $x = time();
5:
6: if (false)
7:    echo "Never executed.";
8:
9: echo var_dump(xdebug_get_code_coverage());
```

..I get this output (I have modified some values to make it more readable):

```
array (size=1)
  '..\testpage.php' => 
    array (size=4)
      3 => int 1
      4 => int 1
      7 => int 1
      9 => int 1
```

The documentation over at Xdebug's site says:

> "The value in the elements represents the total number of execution units on this line have been executed."

Source: http://www.xdebug.com/docs/code_coverage

So apparently the output is wrong. Line 3 and 4 should have been executed three times whereas Xdebug said 1 respectively. Line 6 should have been executed once, Xdebug didn't have a saying at all. Line 7 should definitely not have been executed, yet Xdebug said it did execute once. It should be said that the output stays the same with or without curly braces.

Over at this url: http://xdebug.org/archives/xdebug-general/0377.html

.. Derick Rethans is caught saying (7 years ago!) that somehow the documentation is wrong (and still it is), that Xdebug only returns -1, 0 or 1. However, as my example shows, Xdebug return 1 straight through and the rigged counter seems to make his selection arbitrary. Even if Xdebug did return -1, 0 or 1, I wouldn't know what those values says.

So, anyone of you elite coders have an idea?? And if there's seriously something wrong with Xdebug here, does that mean I can't trust any other applications and plugins used for profiling and code coverage that in their turn use Xdebug? I'm thinking Phing and PHPUnit which seems to be a common marriage.

Also if you feel like elaborating some on this issue; if Xdebug is faulty and as such, all dependent applications, what do you use for code coverage reports in PHP?

**EDIT**: The output listed above using the same code example, is unchanged if I send arguments `XDEBUG_CC_UNUSED` or `XDEBUG_CC_DEAD_CODE` as arguments to `xdebug_start_code_coverage`. I'm beginning to think that Xdebug doesn't work for code coverage at all, not on my system.

Comment: Maybe the PHP parser still has to read it and generate native code for it even if it won't be executed?

Comment: Cole, I'd bet you're thinking of line 7 and yes, that might be the case. But wouldn't Xdebug be completely useless if he couldn't account for such a thing? And still, there's the problem of line 3, 4 and 6.

Comment: I've never used Xdebug so I can't give definite answers, but according to ( http://www.digipedia.pl/usenet/thread/15739/883/ ) it looks like it actually doesn't return the number of times the line is suppose to execute.

Comment: kennypu, in the second URL you can find in my post you'll see that Derick is saying just that. Xdebug is supposed to return -1, 0 or 1. But I can't fully understand what these numbers means. And on my system Xdebug seems to return 1 for every line of code due to some arbitrary selection rendering Xdebug completely useless.

Answer (score 4):

I know there is an issue when using conditionals with indentation syntax.

XDebug only knows about "statements" and doesn't actually understand "lines" even though that's how it is displayed and talked about.

This:

```
1  <?php
2
3  xdebug_start_code_coverage();
4
5  for ($ii = 0; $ii < 3; ++$ii) {
6     $x = time();
7  }
8 
9  if (false) {
10    echo "Never executed.";
11 }
12 
13 echo var_dump(xdebug_get_code_coverage());
```

produces:

```
array(1) {
  ["./test.php"]=>
  array(5) {
    [5]  => int(1)
    [6]  => int(1)
    [7]  => int(1)
    [9]  => int(1)
    [13] => int(1)
  }
}
```

For more information, see: [Edge Cases](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/code-coverage-analysis.html#code-coverage-analysis.edge-cases) in the PHPUnit manual

and other SO questions:

- [Why does PHPUnit show some close-curly-braces as not being covered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8827132/why-does-phpunit-show-some-close-curly-braces-as-not-being-covered)
- [Reaching 100% Code Coverage with PHPUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804095/reaching-100-code-coverage-with-phpunit)
- [code coverage of xDebug and PHPUnit says 100%, in fact it is not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9307774/code-coverage-of-xdebug-and-phpunit-says-100-in-fact-it-is-not?rq=1)

Comment: Thankyou willoller, your comment was sure helpful. But now I'm even more confused. I reproduced your code and got the same output. Makes me wonder why Xdebug says line 7 and not line 11 was executed (or is it __statement__ 7 and __statement__ 11?)?

Comment: On my code 7 is executed because 6 is. 11 is not because 10 is not. The trailing `}` is a bane for anyone who is compulsive about 100% coverage. To address this, phpUnit added `//@codeCoverageIgnore` (?) so you can put it after braces: `} //@codeCoverageIgnore`. Blech.